# how to use functions that return a bool value?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, if-statement

I was writing a program to print 70 prime numbers (7 per row).
I was required to define and use two functions isprime() and printprime.
the program builds and runs but it doesn't print the prime numbers.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code that why I am unable to print the prime numbers?
edit: corrected some mistakes in the for loops and isprime()

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



bool isprime(int num)
{
    bool f = true;
    int c,h = 0;


    for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++)
    {
        c = num % j;
        if (c == 0)
        {
            h++;
            if (h > 2)
            {
                f = false;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return f;
}


void printprime(int x, int y)
{
    bool f = false;
    int  s = 0, h = 0, j = 0, num = 2;
    num = 1; x = 70; y = 7;

    for (int d = 0; d < x; d+=7)
    {
        s = 0;
        cout << " " << endl;
        for (;s < 7;s++)
        {

            f = isprime(num);
            if (f == true)
            {
                cout <<" "<<num;

                num++;
            }
            else if (f == false)
            {
                num++;
                s--;

            }

        }


    }





}


int main()
{
    int  x = 70, d = 0, h = 0, j = 0, y = 7, num = 1;
    num = 1; y = 7;

    printprime(x, y);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isprime()` does not always return a value.  For example what if `num` less than 1. This is Undefined Behavior. But I don't think that this is related to your problem.

Comment: What  is `num % 1` equal to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues,

1. `bool isprime(int num)` is not returning the computed value `f` instead it returning `true` in all the case
2. if number of deviser are more than 2 you can break the loop, instead computing till the end.
3. `printprime` is not collecting return value from `isprime`

Code snippet as follows,

```
bool isprime(int num)
{
    bool f = true;
    int  c,h = 0;
   for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++)
   {
        c = num % j;
        if (c == 0)
        {
            h++;
            if (h > 2) //Check for more than 2 since every prime has min 2 devisers 1 and number iteslf
            {
                f = false;
                break;
            }
        }
   }
   return f;//return the computed value
}

void printprime(int x, int y)
{
   bool f = false;
   int  s = 0, num = 2;
   //Note Num started from 2 as 1 is not a prime
   for (int d = 0;d < x; d+=7)
   {
      s = 0;        
      while (s < 7)
      {             
        f = isprime(num);
        if (f == true)
        {
            cout << num <<" ";    
            s++;
        }
            num++;             
       }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
    int  x = 70, y = 7;
    printprime(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in `printprime()` is likely the cause of your issue:

`for ((d < x); d += y;);`

That trailing semi-colon stops the body of your for loop from executing.